# Как получить все записи пользователя и всех его друзей PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

есть две таблицы: user_posts (user_id => post_text) и friends (idUser => idFriend). В первой соответственно хранятся id пользователя (чей пост) и сам текст поста, а во второй id пользователя и id его друга. Так вот не могу понять, как мне сделать запрос в базу чтобы выбрать все посты текущего пользователя и все посты его друзей.

Посты текущего пользователя получаю так:

```
$get_user_posts = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->query($get_user_posts);
```

Также получил всех друзей этого пользователя:

```
$get_user_friends = "SELECT `idFriend` FROM friends WHERE idUser='$user_id'";
    $user_friends = $conn->query($get_user_friends);
```

Итого есть айди текущего пользователя и его записи, а также массив с айди всех его друзей. И тут мне не ясно как сделать запрос в базу типо:

```
$get_posts = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND user_id='все айди друзей' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

чтобы выбрать все посты текущего пользователя и другого пользователя если это его друг. В этом деле я недавно так что подскажите пожалуйста как мне реализовать данный метод вывода новостей, или если я вообще делаю что-то не так то как лучше и правильно это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: `select * FROM user_posts WHERE user_id=$user_id OR user_id IN(SELECT idFriend FROM friends WHERE idUser=$user_id)`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё просто. Достаточно использовать условие IN. [Вот тут](https://oracleplsql.ru/in-mysql.html) можно ознакомиться подробно:
В вашем случает можно сделать так:

```
$user_friends_as_string = implode(',', $user_friends);
$get_posts = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM user_posts 
    WHERE user_id = $user_id 
        OR user_id in ($user_friends_as_string)
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
```

А лучше сразу с помощью подзапроса:

```
$get_posts = "
    select * 
    FROM user_posts 
    WHERE user_id = $user_id 
        OR user_id IN (
            SELECT idFriend 
            FROM friends 
            WHERE idUser = $user_id
        )
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
```